# Python:how to change string or list elements

Tags: python, string, tabs, split

i've been reading from the file and i have hard time getting rid of "\t"
i've tried using `i.strip().split("\t")[1]` and append it to the list. but if theres more tabs in a row it isnt very useful
for example:
if i do what i described i get

```
z=['\t\t\t\twoman-in-lingerie', 'newspaper-photo', 'reference-to-marie-antoinette', '\tempty-grave', '\t\t\tbased-on-play', '\t\t\tcanadian-humor', '\t\t\tsitcom', 'hypocrisy', 'stripper']
```

now i dont know how to remove those tabs, ive been trying to get trough the list and change each element on its own bit it was unsuccessful

Comment: `strip()` has no problem removing multiple tabs. If your problem is about applying the changes to multiple list items, then you should say that. Show the code where you're having problems, not just the unwanted output.

Comment: i would have shown my code if there wasnt a danger that someone will see it.
i am doing a homework and all are checked with programs that show similarity and if that happens i cannot pass a grade since i loose my chance of entering exam
sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're just trying to remove tabs you can use this list comprehension:

```
l2 = [item.strip('\t') for item in l1]
```

That'll get rid of any leading or trailing tabs on each element.

Comment: thank you for this post, thanks also to other two but you were a bit too advanced for me:)

Comment: @buco - Happy to help.  If you've found the answer you need make sure to mark one as Accepted.  It helps ensure you continue to receive high quality answers and rewards the people who helped you.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want any of the tabs you can use `filter` after reading everything:

```
for item in my_list:
  item = item.filter(lambda x: x != '\t', item)
```

Answer (score 0):

The best you can do is use the `replace` function, replacing tabs ('\t') for empty strings (''):

```
>>> z = ['\t\t\t\twoman-in-lingerie', '\t\t\tsitcom']
>>> map(lambda x: x.replace('\t',''), z)
['woman-in-lingerie', 'sitcom']
```

Answer (score 0):

This might give you an idea:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub('\t+','\t', 'hello\t\t\t')
'hello\t'
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
z = '''\t\t\t\twoman-in-lingerie
newspaper-photo\t\t\t\t          reference-to-marie-antoinette
\tempty-grave
\t\t\tbased-on-play
\t\t\tcanadian-humor\t\t\t
\t\t\tsitcom
hypocrisy\t\t\t\t\tstripper'''


import re

def displ(x):
    return '\n'.join(map(repr,x.splitlines(True)))


print displ(z)

print '-------------------------------'
zt = re.sub('\t+',' ',z)
print displ(zt)

print '-------------------------------'
zt = re.sub('(^\t+)|(\t+)',
            lambda mat: '' if mat.group(1) else ' ',
            z,
            flags = re.MULTILINE)
print displ(zt)

print '-------------------------------'
zt = re.sub('(^[ \t]+)|([ \t]+)',
            lambda mat: '' if mat.group(1) else ' ',
            z,
            flags = re.MULTILINE)
print displ(zt)
```

result

```
'\t\t\t\twoman-in-lingerie\n'
'newspaper-photo\t\t\t\t          reference-to-marie-antoinette\n'
'\tempty-grave\n'
'\t\t\tbased-on-play\n'
'\t\t\tcanadian-humor\t\t\t\n'
'\t\t\tsitcom\n'
'hypocrisy\t\t\t\t\tstripper'
-------------------------------
' woman-in-lingerie\n'
'newspaper-photo           reference-to-marie-antoinette\n'
' empty-grave\n'
' based-on-play\n'
' canadian-humor \n'
' sitcom\n'
'hypocrisy stripper'
-------------------------------
'woman-in-lingerie\n'
'newspaper-photo           reference-to-marie-antoinette\n'
'empty-grave\n'
'based-on-play\n'
'canadian-humor \n'
'sitcom\n'
'hypocrisy stripper'
-------------------------------
'woman-in-lingerie\n'
'newspaper-photo reference-to-marie-antoinette\n'
'empty-grave\n'
'based-on-play\n'
'canadian-humor \n'
'sitcom\n'
'hypocrisy stripper'
```

I use the function **displ()** to display in a manner that shows the escaped characters